# Why may Ubuntu Software not be opening on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-installation

When the shortcut is clicked an activity loading indicator is displayed for a number of seconds in the upper left corner only to disappear without the program having opened. Same happens when searching for Ubuntu Software and selecting it in the list of programs. Potentially connected, is an issue where there's absolutely no response when attempting to open .deb package with Software Installer.

Edit: This is a fresh installation of the stable version of 20.04 and I've tried restarting my computer although in vain.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I haven't been able to open the software center at all since upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04.

Comment: I was hyped for the slick looking Focal LTS release and even refrained from installing the development version in hopes of the best Ubuntu experience waiting around the corner (April 23rd). However, that expectation quickly collapsed.

Answer (score 2):

I removed and reinstall with snap in terminal, then it worked.

```
sudo snap remove snap-store

sudo snap install snap-store
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue after upgrading to 20.04 LTS. One work around is :

1. Click 'Activities' (top left corner)
2. Type 'software' and Enter in Search box
3. We get list of software - Explore, Installed and Update tabs